# How to assert values nested json using asserj?

Tags: java, assertj

I am trying to print and assert **addressLine1** and **postcode** value from the JSON map object using assertJ but facing issues while asserting.

```
{
  "Region": {
    "Test": {
      "address": {
        "addressLine1": "addressLine1",
        "addressLine2": "addressLine2",
        "otherDetails": {
          "postcode": "LS1 4HR",
          "country": "United Kingdom"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I have converted jabove json to **Map<String, Object>** jsonAsMap and tried below:

```
assertThat(jsonAsMap)
                .isNotNull()
                .isNotEmpty()
                .hasEntrySatisfying("Region", Region -> assertThat(Region).hasFieldOrProperty("Test").hasFieldOrProperty("address") )
                   .containsEntry("addressLine1","addressLine1");
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using https://github.com/lukas-krecan/JsonUnit for JSON assertions (or any other JSON assertions library), you will get much better features than AssertJ which does not know JSON.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Actually, we don't want to use multiple libraries for the assertion in the same project and want to assert values of nested JSON using asserj.

Comment: To be clear, AssertJ is not going to add support for JSON assertions as there are better alternatives.

Comment: 100% agree! In particullar take a look at `json-unit-assertj` - Json asserts with with assertJ assertions integrated.